# Tomcat8 log file location

Tags: logging, tomcat8, catalina

My problem is:
I had tomcat 7 on Linux, i install tomcat 8, the log file saved in tomcat 7, how can i direct it to save on tomcat 8.

After i read about it, some solution is to set Catalina base and home to tomcat 8 lib folder.
I tried to find who to set Catalina but with no good result, i fail.

How can i set my app to save log file at tomcat 8?
How can i set Catalina base and home?